# PreparedStatementCallback problem in SQL grammar

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot

I added spring security and get an error, I can not find it, maybe because of inattention

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [select username, password, active from usr by username = ?]; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ОШИБКА: ошибка синтаксиса (примерное положение: "username")


at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:123) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:144) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:175) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:200) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:94) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:124) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) [spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:74) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) [spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) [spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357) [spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270) [spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) [spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92) [spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) [spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) [spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) [spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) [spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) [spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:853) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_211]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_211]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_211]

at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:234) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ОШИБКА: ошибка синтаксиса (примерное положение: "username")


at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2440) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2183) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:308) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:441) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:365) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:143) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:106) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:677) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:616) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
... 64 common frames omitted
```

added all configurations for security, and wrote query

I can't find an error in application.properteis either

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
@Autowired
DataSource dataSource;
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/","/registration").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll();
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.jdbcAuthentication()
            .dataSource(dataSource)
            .passwordEncoder(NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance())
            .usersByUsernameQuery("select username, password, active from usr by username = ?")
            .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select u.username, ur.roles from usr u inner join user_roles ur on u.id = ur.user_id where u.username = ?");
}

spring.datasource.url= jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/sweater 
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=0503040080
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults = false
spring.mustache.expose-request-attributes = true
```

The problem occurs when I try to log in after registration
I think this is not a problem because of the frontend, so the code did not show

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "usr")
public class User {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
private String username;
private String password;
private boolean active;
@ElementCollection(targetClass = Roles.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@CollectionTable(name = "user_roles", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="user_id"))
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private Set<Roles> roles;
```

Comment: I guess your project is not well configured for your database. `bad SQL grammar [select username, password, active from usr by username = ?]` should be with `where username = ?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the faulty line is `.usersByUsernameQuery("select username, password, active from usr by username = ?")`

it should be `.usersByUsernameQuery("select username, password, active from usr WHERE username = ?")` (mixing `WHERE` and incomplete `ORDER BY` statement)